# SQL query - Fetch data from one column separated by comma and display it by row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with fetching data separated by a comma. I want the

Here is my problem

```
Table
ID | TDNO | PREVIOUS_TD |
1  | 14   | 13,12,11    |
2  | 23   | 45,12       |
3  | 32   | 89          |
4  | 55   | NEW         |
```

I want to have a result like this. Example when the user will choose 14 in TD the result should be like this:

```
ID | TD  |
1  | 14  |
2  | 13  |
3  | 12  |
4  | 11  |
```

And when the user will choose 32 in TD the result should be like this:

```
ID | TD  |
1  | 32  |
2  | 89  |
```

when the user will select 23 the result should be like this:

```
ID | TD  |
1  | 23  |
2  | 45  |
3  | 12  |
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: Your database is not in first normal form ([1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)).

Comment: Sorry but I'm still a beginner, can you help me how? @e0k

Comment: Just don't store multiple values in a column like this listt: `13,12,11`, each single value mus be stored in a separate row, probably in a separate child table. A design of your database is wrong.

Comment: Look at the following article - https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql

Comment: This is a very common question on this site try googling.

Comment: @Rak Learn some database design.  This kind of structure will only give you nightmares.

Comment: @Eric Can you show me an example on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You might try a stored procedure or function in your version of SQL.  This is MySql pseudo code and could be very buggy.  Some SQL flavors do not support returning tables:

```
    create function returnCommaSepList (IN myId INT)
    begin
        --
        -- is mtId in the source table?
        SET @previousTD = (
            select PREVIOUS_TD 
            from TheTable
            where ID = myId
        )

        --
        -- if the result is NULL then id was not in the table, return
        if @previousTD IS NULL then return

        --
        -- create a temporary table
        create table #temp (
            id INT primary key autoincrement,
            td int
        )

        --
        -- add myId to the temp table
        insert into #temp (td) values(myId)

        --
        -- prepare to do the string handling.  Step through 
        -- @previousTD looking for commas
        SET @startPos = 0
        SET @commaPos = LOCATE(',', @previousTD, @startPos)

        --
        -- @commaPos will be NULL if the string is NULL
        if @commaPos IS NULL then return

        --
        -- @commaPos will be 0 if there are no commas in the string
        if @commaPos = 0 then 
            SET @previousTD = TRIM(@previousTD)

            --
            -- if @previousTD is empty then return
            if LENGTH(@previousTD) = 0 then return

            --
            -- @previousTD has something in it that is not a comma. 
            -- try to insert it and return
            insert into #temp (td) values(@previousTD)
            select * from #temp order bu id
            return
        endif

        --
        -- should have a @previousTD with at least 1 comma
        while @commaPos > 0
        begin
            SET @item = substring(@previousTD, @startPos, @commaPos)

            insert into #temp (td) values(TRIM(@item))

            SET @startPos = @commaPos + 1
            SET @commaPos = LOCATE(',', @previousTD, @startPos)
        end

        select * from #temp order bu id
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your database, you need to create a new table which has Id of Td and tdNos and have relationships with this. for example:

```
Table TdNos
ID | TDNO | PREVIOUS_TD |
1  | 14   | 13,12,11    |
2  | 23   | 45,12       |
3  | 32   | 89          |
4  | 55   | NEW         |

Table TdNoHistory
TdID|Priority| PREVIOUS_TD |
1   |   1    |      13     |
1   |   2    |      12     |
1   |   3    |      11     |
2   |   1    |      45     |
2   |   2    |      12     |
3   |   1    |      89     |
```

Which for the second table the combination of TdId and Priority are the primary key and it has a relation with table TdNos through TdId column

Comment: I am not familiar with mysql, I can write MS SQL query for you. But what query do you want? What should that query do for you?